# What did King Viserys mean when he said that his brother, Daemon, is the "Visenya" of the family?

Tags: game-of-thrones, house-of-the-dragon

In *House of the Dragon* S01E01 "The Heirs of the Dragon", King Viserys Targaryen had a conversation with his wife, Aemma Arryn, where he compared his brother, Daemon Targaryen to Visenya Targaryen, one of the wives of his ancestor, King Aegon I Targaryen (the first king to sit on the Iron Throne):

> **Aemma:** Rhaenyra has already declared that she is to have a sister.
> **Viserys:** Really?
> **Aemma:** She even named her.
> **Viserys:** Dare I ask?
> **Aemma:** Visenya.
> [...] 
> **Aemma:** She chose a dragon's egg for the cradle that she said reminded her of Vhagar.
> **Viserys:** Gods be good. This family already has its Visenya.
> **Aemma:** Has there been any word from your dear brother?

**What did Viserys mean by this? In what way is Daemon Targaryen the "Visenya" of the family?**

<sup>Note: I'm assuming Viserys was referring to Daemon, based on the conversation. If I'm mistaken, my question should still stand – in what way is that family member, a "Visenya"?</sup>

Comment: I think Visenya was meant to be fiery and fierce in combat; often quick to temper. Those traits seem to follow a lot of Targaryens but Daemon certainly seems to embody them more than some others.

Comment: He's such a Monica!